# Como fazer o login com firebase e consumir os dados de uma api rest local feita com node?

Tags: node.js, firebase, mongodb, react-native

Tenho uma aplicação react-native que consome os dados de uma api feita com o node  e mongo.

E uma aplicação simples, é um CRUD de uma entidade "usuario".Entretando eu tenho a proteção de rotas usando JWT no backend node que tambem gera um token para a autenticacao.

Na apliação react-native  eu faço o login  usando  a api local do node , mas gostaria de fazer o login usando o firebase.

Como posso fazer isso? Fazer o login no Firebase eu sei como, mas a partir dai como proceder para consumir os dados da api do node?

Sei que poderia estar tudo no firebase, mas por uma questão de regras de negocio não pode ser assim.

No momento não estou usando autenticação(token) de nenhum dos lados(nem node , nem firebase). Vou ter que usar os dois  ou devo optar por apenas um deles?

Answer (score 0):

Você já consegue importar o firebase e autenticar certo?

Basta você proteger sua rota com o serviço de autenticação do firebase.

```
const auth = 'SEU_FIREBASE_SERVICE';

router.post('/', auth.FUNCAO_AUTH, controller.post);
router.get('/', auth.FUNCAO_AUTH, controller.get);
```